# SlimFramework 3 input and output to cli while running

Tags: php, command-line-interface, slim

In a normal php-script you can do this:

```
print "run in 3\n"
sleep(1);
print "run in 2\n";
sleep(1)
```

And so on...
You get the output and wait a second and you get the next output.

So now i run a script with slimframework on cli with:

```
$env = \Slim\Http\Environment::mock([
'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
'HTTPS' => true,
'SERVER_NAME' => 'www.domain.tld',
'REQUEST_URI' => '/cli_action'
]);
$settings['environment'] = $env;
...
$app->run();
```

It works fine and do the job ( send emails ).
But the first time i get an output on the cli is when the script ends.
Is there an elegant solution to get an output ( log-messages ) while running?

Thanks for help.

Thomas

Comment: I think Slim uses output buffering by default. When instantiating a new `\Slim\App` object, you pass a `$settings` variable to the constructor. Try to set `$settings ['outputBuffering'] = false;` and see if anything changes .

Comment: Slim seems to always call `ob_start` regardles of the `outputBuffering` setting. The easiest way would be to call `ob_end_clean();` first in your controller. That way output buffering is off and each echo is written unbuffered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slim uses output buffering by default. When instantiating a new \Slim\App object disable output buffering by setting `outputBuffering` to `false`:

```
$settings ['outputBuffering'] = false;
$app = new \Slim\App($settings);
```